# Keyboard battery level inquiry on a Microsoft modern keyboard

Tags: c#, usb, hid

Recently bought a Microsoft modern keyboard with fingerprint id. It has no way to tell the battery percentage besides battery drained red light. 
It registers in device manager as Hid Keyboard Device. Curious if I can write my own driver or figure out if the existing driver can get this information. 
I don't even know if the firmware returns this information in anyway. I haven't done anything in this sense, where do I start?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the app after searching for alternative solutions. Bluetooth LE Explorer has detailed information that can be grabbed for Bluetooth devices. Which for this keyboard does grab battery information.
https://github.com/Microsoft/BluetoothLEExplorer